# Submit form with multiple checkbox in a html table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm currently developing a web application that manages the student, courses, professors of an university. I'm working with spring boot and Jpa. What I'm trying to do now is to mark one or more student as absent in a particular date in a particular lecture. I got in my jsp this code that displays a list of students of a specific sector and year within an html table. Here is the code :

```xml
<c:forEach var="student" items="${students}">
   <tr>
      <td><a style="color: black" href="/management/student/${student.id}">${student.last_name}</a></td>
      <td><a style="color: black" href="/management/student/${student.id}">${student.first_name}</a></td>
      <td><a style="color: black" href="/management/student/${student.id}">${student.sector.label}</a></td>
      <td><a style="color: black" href="/management/student/${student.id}">${student.sector.semester}</a></td>
      <td><input style="margin-left: 50px" type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td><input style="margin-left: 50px" type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td><input style="margin-left: 50px" type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td><input style="margin-left: 50px" type="checkbox" /></td>
   </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

It should be more concrete with a graphical representation of my table:

[image: **enter image description here**]

As you can see there are 4 checkbox inputs, each checkbox for one lecture: There are 4 lectures per day. When click submit, I want to mark all the students as absent simultaneously. How can I perform this task with Spring? 
Please let me know if my explanation is ambiguous.

Comment: What do you mean under `I want to mark all the students as absent`?